# remove elements in dom animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, for-loop

I try to delete some animated elements if they pass the screen height. For that an `array` will be checked in a `for loop`. The array have the id's of the created `div`'s. Theoretically should all div's which have an y position which is higher than the screen height become removed and the values from the array deleted. But now it becomes every n element removed. Know anyone the issue for that? `box = setInterval(newbox, 1000);` affect the behaviour when I change the interval time.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x9j424zy/4/)

```
var cx = wwidth / 100;
var cy = wheight / 100;
var maxpos = cx * 80;

var speed;
var box;
var counter = 0;
var rectids = [];
var deleting;

function newbox() {
    var allpositions = Array(0, cx * 25, cx * 50, cx * 75);
    var rectpos = allpositions[Math.floor(Math.random() * allpositions.length)];
    speed = 0;
    var box = document.createElement('div');

    counter++;
    box.className = "game-btn";
    box.id = 'n' + counter;
    box.style.cssText = "top:" + speed + "px;left:" + rectpos + "px;width:" + cx * 25 + "px;height:" + cy * 10 + "px;position:absolute";
    console.log(rectpos);
    document.body.appendChild(box);
    rectids.push(box.id);
}

function game() {
    box = setInterval(newbox, 1000);
    animaterects = setInterval(function () {
        speed += cx / 300;
        $(".game-btn").css("top", "+=" + speed + "px");
    }, 10);

    deleting = setInterval(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < rectids.length; i++) {
            var x = $("#" + rectids[i]).position();
            if (x.top > wheight) {
                $("#" + rectids[i]).remove();
                rectids.splice(rectids[i]);
            }
        }
    }, 50);
}

game();
```